# CORS and Azure Storage (PHP)

Tags: ajax, azure, blob, azure-storage, cors

I am trying to use the PHP SDK for Windows Azure -- which doesn't have support for CORS nor does it have support for shared access keys.

After rewriting the SDK to allow me to generate SAS's and the requisite query string, and also rewriting it for the Thanksgiving update which allows CORS updates to Storage thru the REST API, I have reached a stuck point.

I successfully create SAS's and can read in files through them.
Likewise, my CORS request was as follows:

```
<StorageServiceProperties>
  <Cors>
    <CorsRule>
      <AllowedOrigins>
         *
      </AllowedOrigins>
      <AllowedMethods>
        GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
      </AllowedMethods>
      <MaxAgeInSeconds>
        500
      </MaxAgeInSeconds>
      <ExposedHeaders>
        x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-customheader
      </ExposedHeaders>
      <AllowedHeaders>
        x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-customheader
      </AllowedHeaders>
    </CorsRule>
  </Cors>
  <DefaultServiceVersion>
    2013-08-15
  </DefaultServiceVersion>
</StorageServiceProperties>
```

To which I receive the response `HTTP_Request2_Response Object ( [version:protected] => 1.1 [code:protected] => 202 [reasonPhrase:protected] => Accepted [effectiveUrl:protected] => <mysite>?restype=service&comp=properties [headers:protected] => Array ( [transfer-encoding] => chunked [server] => Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 [x-ms-request-id] => 59bc0e05-4767-4953-9df1-2d2a6a9054bc [x-ms-version] => 2013-08-15 [date] => Fri, 13 Dec 2013 11:23:49 GMT ) [cookies:protected] => Array ( ) [lastHeader:protected] => date [body:protected] => [bodyEncoded:protected] => 1 )`

I also checked by malforming any part of the input, and it indeed fails and sends 400 Failure responses.

So now I wrote an app on my webpage which should allow users to upload files directly to the storage account, but I still receive the errors

`OPTIONS <mystorage> 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.) jquery.js:8706
OPTIONS <mystorage> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<mysite>' is therefore not allowed access. jquery.js:8706
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <mystorage>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin <mysite> is therefore not allowed access. azure_blob.html:1
error`

And I don't know where to continue from here... I feel like I've enabled CORS, and I feel like I have the SAS working, but it tells me CORS support is off for my storage account, and I'm not sure how to even check if that's true through the REST API / Azure SDK

EDIT: Thanks Guarav... The issue was indeed adding `content-type` to my header

To anybody who sees this soon: I will fix up the code, make it nice, and implement a few other things and then submit a pull request to the PHP SDK so you don't have to go through this again.

I only implemented CORS w/ regards to the new updates.  I will go in and implement the other serviceProperty updates, and perhaps other things, before submitting the request.

Comment: Once you get things fixed up, you should consider submitting a pull request to the [repo](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/tree/master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following headers in your `<AllowedHeaders>` section in CORS request:

- x-ms-* (will take care of headers type x-ms-blob-type etc.)
- Content-Length (I noticed in my experimentation with CORS that this is automatically added by the browser and if I don't include it in my CORS headers, I get 403 error).
- Accept (I noticed in my experimentation with CORS that this is automatically added by the browser and if I don't include it in my CORS headers, I get 403 error).
- Content-Type

Or you can trace the request through a tool like `Fiddler` and see what all request headers are sent in the request and match them against your CORS rule.

Comment: Hey Guarav, I utilized your blog frequently in trying to figure this out... How funny...

Unfortunately these didn't work -- I will attempt to use Fiddler (I have not done so before)

Comment: Small world! Can you share the updated CORS settings? If you want to play with CORS settings, my company released a free tool for that: http://blog.cynapta.com/2013/12/cynapta-azure-cors-helper-free-tool-to-manage-cors-rules-for-windows-azure-blob-storage/. You can use this tool to play with CORS settings.

Comment: Wow awesome. At least I've now seen that I have indeed fixed the CORS settings.  They are indeed all there, in addition to adding the 3 you mentioned.

I am going to assume this means that I have screwed up the latter half, then?  Perhaps I am trying to upload to the wrong location/using SAS incorrectly... I can read successfully after generating the link, but I am just generating a key with a write to a container

Comment: I think the error you're getting is telling you something wrong with CORS setting because you're getting the error during the pre-flight "OPTION" request. Your code hasn't gone to uploading blob yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious -- I've been up for a long time...

i.imgur.com/NnKIOuu.png here is what it shows up as in your app -- I have just blanked out the website name (which is correct).

Comment: Have you checked with fiddler as to what request headers are being sent in the pre-flight request?

Comment: Add content-type also to your headers list. So for the example, I had on my blog post (http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/), I need 4 entries for `<AllowedHeaders>`: Content-Length,Accept,x-ms-*,Content-Type. Try it out

Comment: One more thing I want to mention here: When setting the service version through `DefaultServiceVersion` element, please do ensure that there are no new line characters in the element's value. I ran into an issue with this which resulted in corrupt setting for `DefaultServiceVersion` and all my unauthenticated requests resulted in 500 error from the server.